# How to get HTML SOURCE with Delphi Sydney 10.4.2 and Edge Webbrowser Component

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, tedgebrowser

I have `TEdgeBrowser` in Delphi 10.4.2. I would like to extract a RegEx-based string from the HTML code.
In the past, it was possible with `TWebBrowser` (only with IE 11 or below) as selectedEngine.

But my site wants no IE 11+ anymore. So I have to use the Edge-based `TEdgeBrowser` in Syndey.
I found [this article](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/execute-scripts-and-view-source-with-tedgebrowser/) to get the source by an script call, but with the latest Edge (Evergreen Standalone [from here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)), I always get the `AResultObjectAsJson` will be 'null' (no results are returns).

What can I do to accomplish my task?

Comment: Are you willing to get the source as you said or access to DOM? The difference is that part of the source call JavaScript which produce dynamic content. If you are interested only in source code, then you can a an HTTP component to request that page.

Comment: The problem is I have to interact with the Site in the browser and when it is done (f.e. Select some checkboxes etc) I would like to extract some information from the HTML page code.

Comment: OK, so you need a browser (WbeView2 as far as the EdgeBrowser is concerned) and need access to the DOM to click on buttons and fill data fields. This is done by injecting JavaScript to the page. Have a look at https://blogs.embarcadero.com/execute-scripts-and-view-source-with-tedgebrowser/