# Get Response Text from TEdgeBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, delphi-11-alexandria

How To Get Response Text from TEdgeBrowser?
I call TEdgeBrowser on new form

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm;
  Brws: TEdgeBrowser;
begin
  Form := TForm.Create(Self);
  Form.Width := 700;
  Form.Height := 700;
  Form.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
  Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
  Form.Caption := 'Google';
  Form.OnClose := BrowserFormClosed;

  Brws := TEdgeBrowser.Create(Form);
  TWinControl(Brws).Parent := Form;
  Brws.Align := alClient;
  Form.Show;
  Brws.Navigate('http://google.com');
end;
```

thi code browser from closed

```
procedure TForm1.BrowserFormClosed(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML SOURCE with Delphi Sydney 10.4.2 and Edge Webbrowser Component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67356583/65863)

Comment: It's a web browser having an engine to interpret and render HTML - it's not meant to be used just like a downloader.

Comment: What do you mean by "get response text"? Do you mean something like `document.body.innerText` ? Have you read https://blogs.embarcadero.com/execute-scripts-and-view-source-with-tedgebrowser/ ? That is one way of doing it if you use the previous JavaScript code.